# Can か follow である?

Tags: grammar, words

I know it can't follow だ, but is this possible?

Comment: か can follow だ in subordinate clauses.

Comment: As @snailboat the short answer is yes, but I assume you are looking for some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

か can follow である in subordinate clauses. For example,

> 真実であるかは不明。Whether it is true or not is unknown.
>   (You can also say it as 真実かどうかは不明。)

か can also follow だ in subordinate clauses, as @snailboat says. For example,

> なぜだかわからない。I don't know why.